# Update next column in table if previous column value is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

When a person receives a score, an entry is added into the table `@uniqueScores`:

`Pid | Date | Score`

I have a stored procedure returning a table `@people` with the score columns containing the data from `@uniqueScores` (that fall within the past 3 months)

`Pid | S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5`

I have a small test dataset, however I'm having trouble getting any scores beyond the first score registered to a user to appear in Score2 or beyond.

Here is my test dataset

```
Pid | Date       | Score
 #1 | 2020/07/01 | 8
 #1 | 2020/09/15 | 8
 #2 | 2020/09/21 | 3
 #3 | 2020/10/01 | 5
 #4 | 2020/10/18 | 6
 #4 | 2020/10/31 | 2
```

My update statement, to update the Person column with the data

```sql
BEGIN
  UPDATE @people
  SET    [Score5] = (CASE WHEN ( [p].[Score4] is not null and [p].[Score5] is null ) THEN [us].[Score] ELSE NULL END)
         ,[Score4] = (CASE WHEN ( [p].[Score3] is not null and [p].[Score4] is null ) THEN [us].[Score] ELSE NULL END)
         ,[Score3] = (CASE WHEN ( [p].[Score2] is not null and [p].[Score3] is null ) THEN [us].[Score] ELSE NULL END)
         ,[Score2] = (CASE WHEN ( [p].[Score1] is not null and [p].[Score2] is null ) THEN [us].[Score] ELSE NULL END)
         ,[Score1] = (CASE WHEN ( [p].[Score1] is null ) THEN [us].[Score] ELSE NULL END)
  FROM   @people [p] inner join  @uniqueScores [us]
         on [p].[PersonID] = [us].[PersonID]
  WHERE  [Date] >= @DateLimit -- within the previous 3 months
END
```

However, the query isn't updating the table with any but the first eligible values. The returned table looks like this

```
Pid | S1 | S2   | S3   | S4   | S5
#1  | 8  | null | null | null | null
#2  | 3  | null | null | null | null
#3  | 5  | null | null | null | null
#4  | 6  | null | null | null | null
```

The first table entry which is ineligible to be considered for the table isn't included which is great, however Person #4's second score is also missing.

I've been looking at `PIVOT`, `WHILE` and a `CURSOR` but I've got no closer to making this work. I'm sure I've missed something simple however I just can't see it.

Comment: This, in truth, seems like a design flaw. What happens when a person have a 6th score? Or a 7th? Seems like each score should be a row, not a column.

Comment: 5 is the absolute maximum number of scores that can occur in the 5 month window.

Comment: Until requirements change next week. ;)

Comment: The table being returned with the scores this way is because the frontend datatable displaying the data will have the data laid out in this way, as requested by the product owner. The tables are arranged in such a way that scores (people, comments and media) are held in individual tables, meaning multiple of each type can be added to a parent "report". Having to return multiple person scores for a datatable has thrown up this issue. I'm anything but an expert on SQL, but it doesn't really seem like a design flaw; the table structure is simply dynamic.

Comment: A presentation requirement should never define a design. Storing scores like you have here breaks one of the basic principles of normal form; hence why it's seen as a design flaw. It doesn't scale well, and won't work as soon as requirement change (even if you don't think they well, don't mean that they won't, as many unfortunately souls have learned the hard way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` updates each row *once*.  Preaggregate for multiple updates:

```
UPDATE p
    SET Score1 = us.score_1,
        Score2 = us.score_2,
        Score3 = us.score_3,
        Score4 = us.score_4,
        Score5 = us.score_5
    FROM @people [p] inner join
         (SELECT us.PersonID,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Score END) as score_1,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN Score END) as score_2,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN Score END) as score_3,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN Score END) as score_4,
                 MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN Score END) as score_5
          FROM (SELECT us.*,
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY Date) as seqnum
                FROM @uniqueScores us
                WHERE [Date] >= @DateLimit -- within the previous 3 months
               ) us
          GROUP BY us.PersonID
         ) s
         ON us.PersonID = p.PersonId;
```

Note:  You don't specify what order you want the scores in.  This puts the oldest ones first.  Use `ORDER BY DESC` if you want the newer ones first.

Comment: This code returns the error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
Column '@uniqueScores.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Not sure about adding group by clauses as I am not looking for the sum of the fields.

Comment: @Vurbetan . . . Oops, the `GROUP BY` was in the wrong subquery.

Comment: This just moves the error to Line 60 and to 'us.seqnum'. Also causes a Invalid Column Name error on each 'Score' colmin in the Max Case clauses.

You also have a typo on ") s" should be ") us"

Comment: Thanks for the updates to this Gordon! That has solved the issue. Just to note also, that the data is presorted oldest first in a previous query.

Comment: @Vurbetan . . . There is no such thing as a "sorted table".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You *can* have an identity column that is in a particular order.  Or you can have a clustered index which physically stores the data in order -- but neither of those guarantee that the data is read in order.